# android audio streaming app taking url as input

Tags: android, url, input, audio-streaming

I've made an android app that stream audio from the given URL. But now I want to take the URL as input using EditText. How can I do it?

Here is the previous code :

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!playPause) {
                btn.setText("Pause Streaming");

                if (initialStage) {
                    new Player().execute("https://s156.convertio.me/p/7bTK7awMTh9sKp3yPxU_zA/99b2eb063fbde927ca46f6c96c588547/Merged_fayde_Castl.mp3");
                } else {
                    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                }

                playPause = true;

            } else {
                btn.setText("Start Streaming");

                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                }

                playPause = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is something that I tried but didn't work :

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!playPause) {
                btn.setText("Pause Streaming");

                if (initialStage) {
                    new Player().execute(String.valueOf(stream));
                } else {
                    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                }

                playPause = true;

            } else {
                btn.setText("Start Streaming");

                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                }

                playPause = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you check my answer? Is something missing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's `stream` but I guess it's an `EditText` what you should do is `stream.getText().toString()` or `String.valueOf(stream.getText())` and then pass it as a parameter to your `new Player().execute(stream.getText().toString());`

If your `stream` is an `EditText` I hope you are created as follows :

```
EditText stream = findViewById(R.id.your_edittext_id);
```

Then you can get the text to put in your music player

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (!playPause) {
            btn.setText("Pause Streaming");

            if (initialStage) {
                new Player().execute(stream.getText().toString());
            } else {
                if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                    mediaPlayer.start();
            }

            playPause = true;

        } else {
            btn.setText("Start Streaming");

            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            }

            playPause = false;
        }
    }
});
```

I recommend you to read this [`Java String valueOf()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_valueof.htm) documentation to know what were you doing.

> This method has the following variants, which depend on the passed parameters. This method returns the string representation of the passed argument.